# How to find out if a company has purchased government (or other) bonds?

Tags: stocks, bonds, government-bonds, financial-statements

Looking at a company's [income statement](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL&annual), [balance sheet](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL&annual), and [cash flow](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=AAPL&annual), is it possible to find out if a company has given out a loan to a government or to another business, i.e. government/corporate bonds?

I've been looking at those links and can't seem to figure out if [AAPL](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&ql=1) has given out loans to governments/corporations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in the balance sheet, but the info is not usually that detailed. It is safe to assume that at least some portion of the cash/cash equivalents will be in liquid bonds. You may find more specific details in the company SEC filings (annual reports etc).